# How can I enable the federated engine in mysql after installation?

Tags: mysql, federated-storage-engine

I have mysql 5.1.44:

```
mysql> show engines;
+------------+---------+
| Engine     | Support | 
+------------+---------+
| ndbcluster | NO      | 
| MRG_MYISAM | YES     | 
| BLACKHOLE  | YES     | 
| CSV        | YES     | 
| MEMORY     | YES     | 
| FEDERATED  | NO      | 
| ARCHIVE    | YES     | 
| InnoDB     | YES     | 
| MyISAM     | DEFAULT |
```

I need to enable federated engine in mysql. How can I do it?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Edit `/etc/my.cnf` and in the `[mysqld]` section, add the line:

```
federated
```

It's equivalent to specifying `--federated` on the command line

Comment: Also on Windows the file to modify is `my.ini` in the installation directory (for example `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1`)

Comment: in windows, it also has to be the next thing right after the [mysqld] with a newline, like this-> [mysqld] (newline)
federated

Comment: Can't get this to work, opened my.ini and added `federated` in a newline after `[mysqld]`, still don't see it enabled. I am on `MySQL 5.6.12 on Windows 8`. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: In windows it can be under different folder, not under 'Program Files'. Might be '\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQLServer5.6\my.ini' or similar.

Comment: If you're using Amazons AWS RDS, the Federated engine is not supported.  Just leaving this here to save anyone else the time spent trying it out only to end up frustrated.

Comment: As per other Q&A under Windows when installed with MSI you should edit the file in `%APPDATA%\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0` rather then in `C:\Program Files...\`

Answer (score 41):

I know the post is a little old, but it seems that many people are having issues with federated engines.

When the mysql binaries are installed via yum, you already have the HA (High Availability) plugins.  You simply need to load the plugins within the mysql CLI.

Here is the basic process:

Start mysqld if it is not already started.  Make sure 'federated' is NOT in /etc/my.cnf at this point.

EX: At this time, /etc/my.cnf will look like this from a standard YUM install....

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Log into the mysql CLI with root (or another account with sufficient privilege).

```
Type:   show engines;
```

You should see no FEDERATED engine at this point, like this:

```
mysql> show engines;
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+---    -----------+------+------------+
| Engine     | Support | Comment                                                    |  Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--- -----------+------+------------+
| MRG_MYISAM | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                      | NO               | NO   | NO         |
| CSV        | YES     | CSV storage engine                                         | NO            | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM     | DEFAULT | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance     | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB     | YES     | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| MEMORY     | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables  | NO            | NO   | NO         |
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

--> END PASTE <--

To enable the federate engine, type the following:

```
install plugin federated soname 'ha_federated.so'
```

NOW, when you 'show engines' you will see the FEDERATED Engine, but turned off...

It will look like this:

```
    mysql> show engines;
    +------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
    | Engine     | Support | Comment                                                    | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
    +------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
    | FEDERATED  | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                             | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
    | CSV        | YES     | CSV storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    | MyISAM     | DEFAULT | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance     | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    | InnoDB     | YES     | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys | YES          | YES  | YES        |
    | MEMORY     | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables  | NO           | NO   | NO         |
   | MRG_MYISAM | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    +------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
    6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can now safely add the line 'federated' to the /etc/my.cnf file like this:

```
    [mysqld]
    datadir=/var/lib/mysql
    socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
    user=mysql
    # Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
    symbolic-links=0
    federated

    [mysqld_safe]
    log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
    pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Restart mysqld (service mysqld restart, etc...)

After the restart, go back in to the mysql CLI.

```
Type 'show engines;'
```

You should now see the FEDERATED Engine available and with SUPPORT as YES.

```
    mysql> show engines;
    +------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
    | Engine     | Support | Comment                                                    | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
    +------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
    | FEDERATED  | YES     | Federated MySQL storage engine                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    | CSV        | YES     | CSV storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    | MyISAM     | DEFAULT | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance     | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    | InnoDB     | YES     | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys | YES          | YES  | YES        |
    | MEMORY     | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables  | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    | MRG_MYISAM | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    +------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
    6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And you are done...go forth and create federate tables...

Good luck!

Comment: Basically, one can only add next lines to my.cnf (or my.ini in windows): `[mysqld]
federated`, which can be added to the end of file.

Comment: As you say, yum install version of mysql server don't adds "federated" support. Your answer is so good, you saved my day !!!

Comment: this is the correct answer

Answer (score 7):

> Beginning with MySQL 5.0.64, the
>   FEDERATED storage engine is not
>   enabled by default in the running
>   server; to enable FEDERATED, you must
>   start the MySQL server binary using
>   the `--federated` option. — [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html)

To use the `--federated` [option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld-option-tables.html) in a configuration file drop the `--`.

## Example

> my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
federated
```

Comment: This is not worked: PS C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin> .\mysql.exe --federated -u root -p
mysql: [ERROR] unknown option '--federated'

Answer (score 0):

I was trying Foward Engineer in Workbench and this error appeared to me, so my solution was, Workbench -> Load your Model -> Mysql Model -> click in the table that was showing the error, and click on Edit, after that just change Engine to InnoDB.

MYSQL 8