# Enable FEDERATED ENGINE error

Tags: mysql

I need to enable FEDERATED ENGINE on Mysql (MySQL  version: 5.5.35)

I set in `/etc/my.cnf` file line `federated`.

Restart my mysql server, then check in mysql using command `SHOW ENGINES`, and result is:

```
FEDERATED   NO  Federated MySQL storage engine  NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Also I tried to instal plugin federated , but the result is:

```
mysql> install plugin federated soname 'ha_federated.so';
ERROR 1125 (HY000): Function 'federated' already exists
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210309/how-can-i-enable-federated-engine-in-mysql-after-installation). But with no luck.

FEDERATED still not supported. any Advices?

Comment: Is your MySQL built with federated support enabled? (`-DWITH_FEDERATED_STORAGE_ENGINE`).

Comment: Did you put `federated` in the `[mysqld]` section of my.cnf?

Comment: @Wrikken, where can I check this or change value(from 0 to 1)?

Comment: @Michael, you was right!!I didn't put federated in the [mysqld] section!!)Great!now it works!!You can make an answer and I will accept it!