# MySql Remotely access database

Tags: mysql

I have a two DB server say Server-1 & Server-2, I have installed MySql yog into it, and the servers are able to connect with each other as I have already provided Grant privileges for the servers.

But, I need to build a query which can extract data from more than one servers like -

Select * from Server1.db.Table1, Server2.db.Table2

Is this possible in mysql, if yes, can you please help me to achieve the same.

Thanks

Comment: Use federated engine: http://winashwin.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/mysql-federated-table/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

federated storage engine should help to full fill your requirement.

Follow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210309/how-can-i-enable-federated-engine-in-mysql-after-installation) to enable Federated storage engine in your server from where you are accessing remote table.

--In Server1:

```
CREATE DATABASE fed_remote_db
CREATE USER 'fed_remote_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'fed_remote_password';
GRANT ALL ON fed_remote_db.* TO 'fed_remote_user'@'%';
CREATE TABLE fed_remote_db.fed_table(id INT,NAME VARCHAR(50));
```

--In Server2:

```
CREATE TABLE fed_remote_db.Server1_fed_table (
    id     INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NAME   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) ENGINE=FEDERATED     CONNECTION='mysql://fed_remote_user:fed_remote_password@Server1_IP:3306/fed_remote_db/fed_table';
```

SELECT *
FROM 
fed_remote_db.Server1_fed_table a /* Remember Server1_fed_table table referring to remote server */,
fed_remote_db.server2_fed_table b /* server2_fed_table table referring to local server */
WHERE a.id=b.id;

I believe you can convert above example for your requirements.