# How to enable FEDERATED engine in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, database-performance, federated-storage-engine

How can I enable the FEDERATED storage engine in the MySQL that comes with XAMPP distribution?
I am using Version 1.8.3 of XAMPP with MySQL Version 5.6.16-log.

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ENGINES table shows that FEDERATED support is NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my.ini or my.cnf you should deactivate the option

```
skip-federated
```

For my my.ini I had to change:

```
# commented in by lampp security
# skip-networking
skip-federated
```

to

```
# commented in by lampp security
# skip-networking
# skip-federated
```

Comment: Thanks for the clues. [new command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210309/how-can-i-enable-federated-engine-in-mysql-after-installation) **federated** was to be added there. Now, it works.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer then, so that this question will removed from the unanswered question list.