# cannot install plugin federated in xampp phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I want to create a table with a federated engine so that everytime there is a data change in the server1 table, change data in server2 will also take effect.

Unfortunately when I try to create a table with federated engine this was the error `#1286 - Unknown storage engine 'FEDERATED'`

I search as many as I can on how to install or enable **Federated** storage engine in phpmyadmin xampp but to no avail I did not find a solution.

I need to have a Federated storage engine in my xampp
[[List of storage engine available in my phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG8VO.png)
]

These are the solutions I searched but did not worked for me

1. Put "federated" in the my.ini file under the [mysqld]
2. Downloaded ha_federated.dll located at C:\xampp\mysql\lib\plugin\
3. Install plugin federated soname 'ha_federated.so'

   - 'ha_federated.dll'
   - 'ha_federatedx.dll'
   - 'ha_federatedx.so'

     - All same errors `#1126 - Can't open shared library 'C:\xampp\mysql\lib\plugin\ha_federated.dll' (errno: 2, The specified module could not be found.)`

Does anyone know the solution to this problem I'm encountering?

UPDATE

MySQL returned an empty result set

> select * from information_schema.engines where engine="federated"

[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW2V4.png)

Comment: Check your MySQL and make sure that the federated engine is enabled: `select * from information_schema.engines where engine="federated"`

Comment: hi @tiagoperes, that's what I am asking, how to enable or intall the federated storage engine. i tried the query you gave and sql returned empty result (As updated in the question)

Comment: just to make things clear, FEDERATED should be federated in your my.ini file

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using? One way to verify that is on the main phpMyAdmin page, towards the right side of the page is the version information.

Comment: According to the MySQL documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-storage-engine.html), your MySQL must be compiled with `-DWITH_FEDERATED_STORAGE_ENGINE` and your MySQL server binary must be started with the `--federated` option. Did you do both of those? Also, this related question may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010788/how-to-enable-federated-engine-in-xampp#25011424