# uses of federated table doesn't work

Tags: mysql, federated-table

I wanted to create a federated table so I have the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `ldap` (
  `Key_Id` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `distinguishedName` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `givenName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sn` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employeeID` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employeeType` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `department` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telephoneNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `facsimileTelephoneNumber` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `homePhone` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `otherTelephone` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `otherMobile` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `otherHomePhone` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ST` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Mail` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `physicalDeliveryOfficeName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `streetAddress` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postalCode` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `L` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sAMAccountName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `houseIdentifier` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `info` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `showInAddressBook` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `displayName` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `IX_LDAP_distinguishedName` (`distinguishedName`),
  KEY `IX_LDAP_employeeID` (`employeeID`)
)
ENGINE=FEDERATED
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CONNECTION='mysql://admin:xxx@cdmysql:3305/node/ldap';
```

I have in the ldap table more then 1000 rows. I want to recreate this table on the other db and I thought I have to use federated table. But when I use the code above, the ldap table is created, but with no rows. I don't have any errors. what can be the problem?

My version of MySQL is 5.1.73

Comment: Do you mean to say that you wanted to create a copy of `ldap` table with data from some other environment?

Comment: yes it is what I mean

Answer (score -1):

look at this Post

[how can i enable federated engine in mysql after installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210309/how-can-i-enable-federated-engine-in-mysql-after-installation)

There is the answer, I had the same issue than you and to solve it I had to Enabled Federated engine in Mysql.

Saludos! :)