# How can I a call stored procedure on a remote MySQL Ubuntu server?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, stored-procedures, remote-access

I have an Ubuntu server with MySQL and many Stored Procedures (server A) and another Ubuntu server with MySQL (server B).

I'd like to populate the database on server B with data from the stored procedures on server A.

At this point I'd like to test the connection with no success.

I tried this on server B:

```
mysql> EXEC server_A_IP.DB_name.username.sp_courses();
```

But it gives this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'EXEC
>   server_ip.db_name.owner.sp_courses()' at line 1

This is an example of what I'd like to do eventually:

On server B I have this table:

```
mysql> describe Course;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| CID   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| name  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The Stored Procedure on Server A returns data like this:

```
call sp_courses();-- where the parameter indicates level 1.Returns [courseID, name]

1   CS1
2   CS2
10  CS3
12  CS4
13  CS5S
```

Can I fill data into the table from stored procedure on a different server?

Comment: There is a way but I need to know if  `sp_coursesForYear` procedure is a mere select on table... and if you can show us some code of that.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you can't call a procedure stored in server A from server B.

What I'd do is:

1. Modify the procedure so the output is stored in a table.
2. Use `mysqldump` to dump the data of this output table and store it in the other server.

Example:

On server A, the procedure can be something like this:

```sql
delimiter $$
create procedure my_procedure()
begin
    -- Create a table to store the output:
    drop table if exists temp_result;
    create table temp_result (
        CID int not null primary key,
        name varchar(50)
    );
    -- Populate the table
    insert into temp_result
        select ...
end $$
delimiter ;
```

On server B, execute the following statement in the shell, *not in MySQL CLI*:

```sh
mysqldump <options_A> db_A temp_result --no-create-db --add-drop-table | mysql <options_B> db_B
```

where:

- `<options_A>` The options needed to connect to server A from server B:
  `-h <IP of server A> -u <user> -p<password>`.
- `db_A` The database in server A where the result is stored
- `<options_B>` The options needed to connecto to server B:
  `-h localhost -u <user> -p<password>`

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to send data to a remote table using stored procedures, the trick is use federated tables. I created tables in two servers and stored procedure to reproduce your situation:

1. SERVER A: create table and insert some data

   ```
   create table course_A
   (
     CID int not null primary key,
     name varchar(50),
     year int
   );

   insert into course_A values 
   (1,'CS1P',2016),
   (2,'CS1Q',2016),
   (109,'CS1-CT',2016),
   (120,'CS1PX',2016),
   (121,'CS1S',2016);
   ```
2. SERVER B: create a table with structure

   ```
   create table course_B
   (
     CID int not null primary key,
     name varchar(50)
   );
   ```
3. SERVER A: create a remote table connected to table in server B:

   ```
   create table course_B_remote
   (
     CID int not null primary key,
     name varchar(50)
   )
   ENGINE=FEDERATED
   CONNECTION='mysql://user:password@SERVER_B_IP:3306/database/course_B';
   ```

   Now, whatever to do with `table_B_remote` affects directly to `table_B` in SERVER B.
4. SERVER A: Create stored procedure to send the query results from `course_A` table to `course_B_remote`:

   ```
   delimiter $$
   drop procedure if exists sp_coursesForYear$$
   create procedure sp_coursesForYear(p_year int)
   begin

       /*
        Your procedure code...
       */

       insert into course_B_remote (CID,name)
       select  CID, name 
       from course_A   
       where year = p_year;

   end$$
   delimiter ;
   ```
5. Now, test the stored procedure:

   ```
   server A prompt> call sp_coursesForYear(2016);
   Query OK, 5 rows affected (0,00 sec)
   ```
6. Check if it worked:

   ```
   server B prompt> select * from  course_B;
   +-----+--------+
   | CID | name   |
   +-----+--------+
   |   1 | CS1P   |
   |   2 | CS1Q   |
   | 109 | CS1-CT |
   | 120 | CS1PX  |
   | 121 | CS1S   |
   +-----+--------+
   5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
   ```
7. Enjoy!

Maybe you will need to alter your procedures to use the `FEDERATED` tables.
No enable `FEDERATED` tables see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210309/how-can-i-enable-federated-engine-in-mysql-after-installation).

Comment: Thank you. However, I don't have access to server A, I can only call its SPs from server B. Is there a solution where I can only access server B? Cheers.

Comment: @Sei you must access to both servers to configure parameters