# How to call stored procedure from another server stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How can I call a stored procedure on another server from a stored procedure in MySql?

For example, I have stored_procedure_1 on server_1 and stored_procedure_2 on server_2.

I want stored_procedure_1 to call stored_procedure_2.

How do I write this?

Comment: Never had to do this but the call syntax would suggest you cannot https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/call.html.

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798210/how-can-i-a-call-stored-procedure-on-a-remote-mysql-ubuntu-server